# How to retrieve what was inserted by one out of two insert queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, dbcontext

I'm building an API method that takes in, among other things, a dictionary and attempts to insert the data into the database. The data essentially is split out in a parent/child type relationship that is enforced via foreign keys. The database structure is designed this way for specific reasons and cannot change.

I originally wrote this using Entity Framework, but performance testing revealed it was far too slow with large requests due to all of the querying and processing required. Sending all of the data to the database and allowing it to figure out which records should be inserted was much, much faster (we're talking 20-30 minutes down to 20-30 seconds).

Here's my problem: Originally, I was simply returning the number of records that were inserted with ExecuteNonQuery. Easy, right? Now, I need to be able to find out which parent records had a child record successfully inserted. So, I've been trying to refactor this to facilitate it.

For clarity, I'm not interested in which parent records were inserted - I'm only interested in which parent records had a new child record inserted referencing said parent. This way, I can inform the API caller which records were not inserted successfully by comparing with what the caller passed to the API. The best way I can see so far is to use the `OUTPUT` clause in the child `INSERT` query to get the ParentIDs that were inserted and store them in a table variable. Then I can just look up the IDs against the parent table and get the names for my comparison. But that necessitates using a reader, and since multiple SQL statements are involved, bad things are happening.

The code as currently presented results in the following exceptions:

> The transaction operation cannot be performed because there are pending requests working on this transaction. This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable. Test method My.Long.Project.Name.UnitTest.UnitTestMethod threw exception: System.InvalidOperationException: This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.

While fixing these exceptions is valuable, I'm not as interested in solving them as I am in solving the actual problem. If there's a different path I can take that is extremely fast and provides the output I need, then I'll investigate it. Here's my code. I'm hoping that what I intend to do is clear and any help/guidance/suggestions would be appreciated.

```
using (Context dbContext = createDbInstance())
{
    //Not happy about setting MultipleActiveResultSets
    string conn = dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString + ";MultipleActiveResultSets=True";

    SqlCommand newInsertCmd = new SqlCommand {Connection = new SqlConnection(conn)};

    //Set up input variables here, including a TPV

    SqlDataReader reader;
    List<string> results = new List<string>();

    newInsertCmd.Connection.Open();
    SqlTransaction sqlTran = newInsertCmd.Connection.BeginTransaction();
    newInsertCmd.Transaction = sqlTran;

    try
    {
        //The two insert statements work just fine. The other junk here (including the OUTPUT clause) is brand new
        const string qryInsertTrans =
            @"INSERT INTO Parent ([Name], [CreateDate])
            SELECT n.Name, GETUTCDATE() [CreateDate]
            FROM
                @NewRecords n
                LEFT JOIN Parent p ON n.Name = p.Name
            WHERE
                p.ParentID IS NULL;

            DECLARE @OutputVar table(
                ParentID bigint NOT NULL
            );

            INSERT INTO Child ([ParentID], [SomeText], [CreateDate])
            OUTPUT INSERTED.ParentID INTO @OutputVar
            SELECT p.ParentID, n.Text, GETUTCDATE() [CreateDate]
            FROM
                @NewRecords n
                INNER JOIN Parent p ON n.Name = p.Name
                LEFT JOIN Child c ON p.ParentID = c.ParentID AND c.SomeCol = @SomeVal
            WHERE
                c.ChildID IS NULL;

            SELECT p.Name
            FROM Parent p INNER JOIN @OutputVar o ON p.ParentID = o.ParentID";

        newInsertCmd.CommandText = qryInsertTrans;
        reader = await newInsertCmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            results.Add(reader["Name"].ToString());
        }

        sqlTran.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        try
        {
            sqlTran.Rollback();
        }
        catch (Exception exRollback)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exRollback.Message);
            throw;
        }

        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        newInsertCmd.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I might well be, but isn't the use of transactions only when you're sending multiple queries? In other words, if you had this split out into several `SqlCommand`s? I was under the impression that a single `SqlCommand` effectively acts as a transaction in and of itself and that SQL would roll back anything if execution of the command failed mid-way.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen: A few of things - 1) You may be right (I haven't read anything yet that says you're wrong). 2) The `INSERT` statements were originally separated into two different commands using the same connection. 3) I was told to use them by someone in my office who is paid more than I am (but I can change anything if I can defend the change).

Comment: Fair enough. Alright. Yeah, I'm not sure. They certainly shouldn't be hurting, but it might be a valuable debugging step to remove the transaction aspect. If nothing else, that might narrow down the issue.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen: That was a solid idea. I have a unit test that attempts to insert records that already exist. The controller will send the records that exist to the output window in VS. Low and behold, removing the transaction code results in a successful run with the expected results. Having said that, I'll need to look into this a bit more to understand why it was causing issues and if I'm still protected if something goes wrong in the database.

Comment: Interesting. On second thought, I'm actually unfortunately less convinced that a SqlCommand is atomic, which means you probably will want that transaction in there. But yes, it's definitely a good piece of information to know that it works without it. I wonder, it's probably not best practice, but could you declare the transaction in T-SQL itself? As in, using `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and all that? Again, it might not be ideal, but it could give you some more information. And it might be "good enough," although it would be good to know the original problem as well.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen: Adding that poses no problems. I'll have to devise a way to make the second `INSERT` statement for the child table to fail somehow.

Comment: I forced a deadlock situation on the child table and made sure that C# would be blocked. Looks like it worked just fine and rolled back the records for the parent. Only thing left to solve, I think, is why I can't manage the transaction using ADO.NET.

Comment: 1) a SqlCommand represents a batch of queries, not a transaction. Without a declared TRANSACTION, each individual query is a transaction by itself. 2) quite possibly the issue is the async reader and "await" statement. Try doing a regular ExecuteReader and no "await".

Comment: @srutzky, good to know. Thanks. Ellesedil so is it all working now? As in, the goal is making good better, as compared to fixing what's broken? The await matter would be another interesting test.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen: Yep, it's working. I'll check out the async behavior Monday morning. Feel free to post an answer.

Comment: @Ellesedil, I just re-read one of your comments above. You should wrap all of your SQL in an TRY / CATCH block. I guess I can post an answer to format better than in a comment.

Comment: @srutzky, am I not already doing that?

Comment: @Ellesedil, I meant that if you are handling the transaction in the SQL, then you should likewise have a SQL-based TRY / CATCH as it makes managing that stuff _much_ easier. I posted an answer to better explain as well as introduce a more likely cause: not closing the reader ;-).

Comment: @srutzky good call on the reader. A previous version had it and didn't make a difference.

Comment: It sounds like @srutzky has a better grasp of the issue than I, but I'm glad the three of us could at least get you to the stage of it working. It mightn't be a bad idea for you to add in some `using` blocks just to make sure everything is getting disposed appropriately. I'm not in an IDE right now to say specifics, but I know most of the data-related classes do implement `IDisposable`. It's one of those magic fixes that doesn't necessarily make much sense, but it might clear some things up. Particularly since it sounds like your error is complaining about something not getting disposed.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen, thanks, but that remains to be seen ;-). I do know that the SqlDataReader must be closed. And since it is the result of the query, it makes sense that it should be closed before the transaction is committed. But I haven't tried to reproduce this scenario so for now it is just an educated guess. So it will be interesting to see if any of this solved the issue.

Comment: I've posted an answer since code formatting is nicer there, but I think that should do it. I'm still a fan of @srutzky's way of doing things, which the transaction embedded in the T-SQL text, just since that seems lighter-weight and less prone to failures, but at least this way is more expandable. In fact if you went this route, I'd be a little tempted to pull out the first insert and keep it separate from the second, just for readability if nothing else. If you house them in a SqlTransaction that should be no risk there.

Comment: On the other hand of all this, I still don't see why "MultipleActiveResultSets" is necessary. It would make sense if you were using the same connection and forgetting to close the reader, since then multiple result sets would, in fact, be active on the same connection concurrently. But since you're just opening the connection and closing it, I don't see a need for that. You can probably get rid of it now that we've cleaned up the code a bit, whichever way you choose to go with that.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen: Unfortunately, my understanding is that the parameters would be sent across multiple times if i were to send the statements separately, even if using the same connection. Variables declared in the first statement are not persevered for the second statement. Since I'm sending a table value parameter, that is not ideal.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen: also, I realized on Friday after I posted this question that i didn't need MultipleActiveResultSets. I was under the impression i needed it when initially looking into this, but suspected it was unnecessary as we worked through this question. I removed it by the time we put some working code together.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But I'm not sure I see which parameters are getting carried through. I'm just talking about splitting into two queries, not three. Take a look at the answer I posted below, in the second code example. It's definitely not a big deal, it just might simply things a bit.

Comment: And yeah, I mean MultipleActiveResultSets isn't a big deal, I just thought I'd bring it up since you had a comment saying you'd prefer not to have it. :)

Comment: @MatthewHaugen: The NewRecords variable is in the FROM clause of both INSERT SELECTS. That is loaded as a 2 column tpv and could contain thousands of entries, with one of the columns being a NVARCHAR(MAX).

Comment: Fair enough, one command it is! I was actually wondering when I first came across this question where that parameter was coming from, but I figured it irrelevant to the solution. So do your problems seem to be solved, then, via one approach or the other?

Comment: @MatthewHaugen I still need to find some time to see if there is an async or disposal issue. Right now, I have to work on the documentation _sigh_. But, I'll definitely be pinpointing the particular issue this week and get back to everyone. As it stands, I know I have a feasible solution. Now I just need to identify the cleanest solution.

Comment: Documentation: it's awful when other people don't do it, and awful when we have to. But yeah, sounds good. I look forward to hearing how it all plays out! I'd definitely try the disposal approach before the async/await. I think async/await is a good troubleshooting step, but I think the disposal will solve the problem once and for all. Best of luck!

Comment: @MatthewHaugen and Ellesedil, I just added some info to my answer (where it says "Edit") that again seems to point to not just closing the DataReader, but closing it _before_, not after, the commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait, I just looked over it again and it all makes perfect sense! I don't know if these few days have left me delirious or wise (is there even a difference?) but I'm virtually positive that adding usings will do the trick.

Here's the code, granted I of course haven't tested or even compiled this so I might be off on a few details:

```
using (Context dbContext = createDbInstance())
{
    //Not happy about setting MultipleActiveResultSets
    string conn = dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString + ";MultipleActiveResultSets=True";

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
    using (var newInsertCmd = new SqlCommand(connection))
    {
        newInsertCmd.Connection.Open();
    //Set up input variables here, including a TPV

    List<string> results = new List<string>();

    using(SqlTransaction sqlTran = newInsertCmd.Connection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        newInsertCmd.Transaction = sqlTran;

        try
        {
            //The two insert statements work just fine. The other junk here (including the OUTPUT clause) is brand new
            const string qryInsertTrans =
                @"INSERT INTO Parent ([Name], [CreateDate])
                SELECT n.Name, GETUTCDATE() [CreateDate]
                FROM
                    @NewRecords n
                    LEFT JOIN Parent p ON n.Name = p.Name
                WHERE
                    p.ParentID IS NULL;

                DECLARE @OutputVar table(
                    ParentID bigint NOT NULL
                );

                INSERT INTO Child ([ParentID], [SomeText], [CreateDate])
                OUTPUT INSERTED.ParentID INTO @OutputVar
                SELECT p.ParentID, n.Text, GETUTCDATE() [CreateDate]
                FROM
                    @NewRecords n
                INNER JOIN Parent p ON n.Name = p.Name
                LEFT JOIN Child c ON p.ParentID = c.ParentID AND c.SomeCol = @SomeVal
                WHERE
                     c.ChildID IS NULL;

                SELECT p.Name
                FROM Parent p INNER JOIN @OutputVar o ON p.ParentID = o.ParentID";

            newInsertCmd.CommandText = qryInsertTrans;
            using(var reader = await newInsertCmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    results.Add(reader["Name"].ToString());
                }
            }
            sqlTran.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);

            try
            {
                sqlTran.Rollback();
            }
            catch (Exception exRollback)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(exRollback.Message);
                throw;
            }

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you're looking for something that's a little more, in my opinion at least, readable:

```
using (Context dbContext = createDbInstance())
{

    List<string> results = new List<string>();

    //Not happy about setting MultipleActiveResultSets
    string conn = dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString + ";MultipleActiveResultSets=True";

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
    {
        newInsertCmd.Connection.Open();
        using(SqlTransaction sqlTran = newInsertCmd.Connection.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                using (var parentInsert = new SqlCommand(connection))
                {
                    parentInsert .Transaction = sqlTran;

                    //Set up input variables here, including a TPV

                    newInsertCmd.CommandText = 
                            @"INSERT INTO Parent ([Name], [CreateDate])
                            SELECT n.Name, GETUTCDATE() [CreateDate]
                            FROM @NewRecords n
                            LEFT JOIN Parent p ON n.Name = p.Name
                            WHERE p.ParentID IS NULL;";

                    await newInsertCmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                }

                using (var childInsert = new SqlCommand(connection))
                {
                    childInsert.Transaction = sqlTran;

                    //Set up input variables here, including a TPV

                    newInsertCmd.CommandText = 
                          @"DECLARE @OutputVar table(
                              ParentID bigint NOT NULL
                          );

                          INSERT INTO Child ([ParentID], [SomeText], [CreateDate])
                          OUTPUT INSERTED.ParentID INTO @OutputVar
                          SELECT p.ParentID, n.Text, GETUTCDATE() [CreateDate]
                          FROM NewRecords n
                          INNER JOIN Parent p ON n.Name = p.Name
                          LEFT JOIN Child c ON p.ParentID = c.ParentID AND c.SomeCol = @SomeVal
                          WHERE c.ChildID IS NULL;

                          SELECT p.Name
                          FROM Parent p INNER JOIN @OutputVar o ON p.ParentID = o.ParentID";

                   using(var reader = await childInsert.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                   {
                       while (reader.Read())
                       {
                           results.Add(reader["Name"].ToString());
                       }
                   }
                }
                sqlTran.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);

                try
                {
                    sqlTran.Rollback();
                }
                catch (Exception exRollback)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(exRollback.Message);
                    throw;
                }

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And for good measure, the embedded option:

```
using (Context dbContext = createDbInstance())
{
    //Not happy about setting MultipleActiveResultSets
    string conn = dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString + ";MultipleActiveResultSets=True";

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
    using (var newInsertCmd = new SqlCommand(connection))
    {
        newInsertCmd.Connection.Open();
        //Set up input variables here, including a TPV

        List<string> results = new List<string>();

        //The two insert statements work just fine. The other junk here (including the OUTPUT clause) is brand new
        const string qryInsertTrans =
            @"BEGIN TRY
                BEGIN TRANSACTION;

                INSERT INTO Parent ([Name], [CreateDate])
                SELECT n.Name, GETUTCDATE() [CreateDate]
                FROM @NewRecords n
                    LEFT JOIN Parent p ON n.Name = p.Name
                WHERE p.ParentID IS NULL;

                DECLARE @OutputVar table(
                ParentID bigint NOT NULL
                );

                INSERT INTO Child ([ParentID], [SomeText], [CreateDate])
                OUTPUT INSERTED.ParentID INTO @OutputVar
                SELECT p.ParentID, n.Text, GETUTCDATE() [CreateDate]
                FROM @NewRecords n
                    INNER JOIN Parent p ON n.Name = p.Name
                LEFT JOIN Child c ON p.ParentID = c.ParentID AND c.SomeCol = @SomeVal
                WHERE c.ChildID IS NULL;

                SELECT p.Name
                FROM Parent p INNER JOIN @OutputVar o ON p.ParentID = o.ParentID

                COMMIT TRAN;                          
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRAN;
            THROW;
            END CATCH;";

        newInsertCmd.CommandText = qryInsertTrans;
        using(var reader = await newInsertCmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                results.Add(reader["Name"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up settling on just wrapping reader in a `using` statement. That actually handles the disposal quite nicely, then the commit can fire. Everything else is still pretty much the same. I did this instead of handling the transactions in the SQL itself so that I can engage our logging process for any issues that occur during the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

The

```
The transaction operation cannot be performed because there are
pending requests working on this transaction. This SqlTransaction
has completed; it is no longer usable.
```

error is quite possibly due to the `ExecuteReaderAsync` and the `await`. Try a regular `ExecuteReader` and no `await`. This *should* allow the .Net-initiated transaction to work.

If that doesn't fix it, it could be that you are not calling `reader.Close();` in your `finally` block (and this really should be done to not have that orphaned resource). And actually, looking at the error message again, it could be that the `reader.Close();` is needed just after the `while` but before the `sqlTran.Commit();`.

However, since you have a single SqlCommand call there really is no need for a .Net-initiated transaction, right?  This could all be handled cleanly in the SQL by structuring it as follows:

```
BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;

  <your code>

  COMMIT TRAN;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  ROLLBACK TRAN;
  THROW;
END CATCH;
```

If the first INSERT (into Parent) fails, then the second INSERT (into Child) will be skipped as control will immediately pass to the CATCH block.

**EDIT:**
I just came across the following in the MSDN documentation for the IDataReader interface that supports my contention that the open SqlDataReader is the culprit and that it needs to be closed *before* the Commit can be issued. In the "Remarks" section of the [Read()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.read.aspx) method, it says:

> While the data reader is in use, the associated connection is busy
>   serving the IDataReader. This is the case until Close is called.

This should explain why "a prior attempt that did close the DataReader did not solve the problem" (paraphrase of statement made in a comment on the question) because most likely you were closing it in the `finally` clause which is too late given that the transaction is committed at the end of the `try` block.

Comment: I will definitely check that out. That makes sense to me.

Comment: Your suggestion that it was the reader being left open was correct. However, the best way to take care of that was to wrap the reader with a `using` statement. Trying to close the reader, if it were open, in the catch statement was a problem, so `using` was the best option.

Comment: @Ellesedil: closing the reader in the catch block should not be a problem; I do that all of the time. You already have the variable declared outside of the try. Perhaps the only issue was that you don't have it defaulted to `null` as in: `SqlDataReader reader = null;`. But I never use `using` statements and always close my resources, though I usually do it in the `finally` block as that will happen regardless so I only need to have it once in the code (unless there is a specific order of events issue that makes that not work, but that is rare). Either way, glad I could help.